"Hungry-hearted mothers"
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part I, Aberfan, chapter 5)

(In the vestry where the dead bodies of young schoolkids buried alive are to be identified. William, one of the embalmers, has sometimes to go out to show the mothers and fathers a shoe or a piece of cloth for identifying)


Sometimes, all William has to take outside is a scrap of fabric, a hair bobble, a shoe. Yet it doesn't take much to send a mother's body lurching towards him, saved and destroyed in the same second. These eagle-eyed, hungry-hearted mothers could identify their children by a single fingernail.

I don't really know what the author is intending to say with hungry-hearted. I assume it could mean something like mothers/fathers are being stricken with unquenched or unsatisfied concern about their kids.

You're right. It's used in various ways, but means that they are lacking something -- not a physical hunger, they something to satisfy an emotional or spiritual need. It seems to be used both of people who're desperate and needy, and those with great appetites for life, so it's quite vague. It's found in Tennyson's Ulysses; I don't know if he coined the phrase.

Here, their hearts are no longer filled [food metaphor] by their kids, who are dead. Easy to understand.

Since the heart does not hunger literally, you must understand it as a metaphor, as it is not an idiom with a fixed meaning. Metaphors are open to interpretation, and that sort of interpretation is not on-topic here. There is, however, a cliche expression "hungry for news".

@lambie - What do you understand by be no longer filled by their kids?

People feel their hearts filled by all sorts of things; joy, love, love for kids, husbands, family, pets, causes, religious stuff,  etc.

That, indeed, astonishes me greatly. The hearts of mothers and fathers will be filled by their dead kids for good and all - they will never forget them as sure as eggs is eggs.

My heart is filled by my child.. My child died. Now, my heart is no longer filled. My heart is hungry to be filled again.
